# while deploying spring boot application on docker i am getting this error

Tags: spring-boot, docker

[image]this is my docker details.
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           19.03.8
API version:       1.40
Go version:        go1.12.17
Git commit:        afacb8b
Built:             Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
Engine:
Version:          19.03.8
API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version:       go1.12.17
Git commit:       afacb8b
Built:            Wed Mar 11 01:37:20 2020
OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
Experimental:     true

Comment: Is virtualization enables in the BIOS?

Comment: Thank you @DebarghaRoy in bios I enabled virtualization and the problem is solved.